# Magento - Integrating Wordpress into Magento for the homepage

Tags: wordpress, magento, content-management-system, integration

I currently have a Magento store where I'm using a CMS page as the homepage. I want to integrate my wordpress blog (hosted on the same server) into this CMS page. It would show the latest blog post and preferably have the comment function available on the front page. The first thing I considered was using the Wordpress Loop on the Magento CMS page, but it doesn't seem like it allows PHP.

One other thought I had was to create the homepage using modules or blocks. To be honest, I've never created a module or block so I'm not all that familiar with what is involved. The CMS page that I had created is simply an image slider/carousel (nivo-slider) and some photos with links. None of the content actually needs to be done with CMS, it just needs to be presented within my Magento theme/framework. All homepage updates will be handled by myself, so I can bypass the CMS system all together and just update modules if it turns out that the modules solution will allow me to have both the Wordpress blog and nivo-slider on the same page.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution at Part 2 of the following link:
http://addoa.com/blog/easy-wordpress-and-magento-integration

Here's a quick summary of the steps (for a full explanation, click the link above):

> 1) Create a bare-bones WordPress theme file that skips all of the styles, header, and footer and just displays content.
>
> 2) Create a page in WordPress that uses your new bare-bones template.
>
> 3) Create a template file in Magento to embed your newly created WordPress page into a Magento page.
>
> 4) Place the block based on your new template on the Magento CMS page you want the blog content to display on

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can try is setting wordpress as the main site and style it to match your magento styling.  Then the visitor will have a streamlined experience from a UI standpoint.  One gotcha would be if you want comments open on Wordpress then you'd have 2 accounts you'd have to reconcile for wordpress and magento.

Answer (score 2):

The FishPig extension now supports this functionality so you achieve this by following these steps:

- Upgrade to the latest version of FishPig's WordPress Integration
- Login to your Magento Admin and go to WordPress > Settings Blog / Plugins
- Find the Layout option and set 'Blog as Magento Homepage' to Yes
- Save the page and voila, you have it: WordPress as your Magento homepage using your Magento theme in under 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You will be wanting the Fishpig integration:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fishpig/extension/3958/fishpig_wordpress_integration

Not only is it free, it is also actively maintained.

You can also do an Apache redirect for the root/home page to a wordpress page of your choosing. In that way you don't have to have the problem of adding something to the Magento homepage and maybe have something fancy in Wordpress.

Comment: I tried Fishpig out, but I couldn't quite figure out how to get the desired results of displaying my Wordpress blog on a CMS page along with some other Magento specific content. It created new pages with my blog integrated with the Magento theme. It's possible I missed something, though.

Comment: Try giving Mr FishPig an email - the module has came a long way and your feedback/problems might be welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

hopefully i've understood your question!
the following article may be of help to you (it outlines how to use the fishpig extension and to pull out the latest posts as part of a magento block on your homepage):
[adding recent posts to magento homepage](http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration/adding-recent-posts-to-the-homepage/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use blog extension of magento.
You can get it free form magento site http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aheadWorks/extension/1516/blog-extension-by-aheadworks

Thanks